# Show that this language is in NP $\cap$ coNP

Tags: np-hard, np

Say $\ell: \{0,1\}^\ast \to \{0,1\}^\ast$ is a one-to-one polynomial-time computable function that preserves length. Consider the language $$L = \Bigl\{v \;\Big|\; \exists u: \bigl(u_1 = 1 ~~\text{and}~~ \ell(u) = v\bigr) \Bigr\}.$$ How do I prove that $L$ is in $\mathsf{NP} \cap \mathsf{coNP}$? Basically, what would appropriate witnesses for $L$ in $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{coNP}$ be?

Comment: What have you tried? For $v \in L$, can you think of an easy way to *prove* that $v \in L$?

Comment: The $NP$ witness is fairly straightforward. But for $coNP$, I thought of listing all $2^{n-1}$ candidates $(c_1,..,c_x)$ for $u$ and then checking to make sure $\ell(c_i) \neq v$ $\forall c_i$.

Comment: ^ And that is a bad plan because it's exponential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use the fact that $\ell$ is one-to-one, and so to every $v$ there corresponds a unique $u$ such that $\ell(u) = v$.

Comment: I can't assume that the inverse of $\ell$ is computable in polynomial time. But otherwise, are you alluding to something different?

Comment: When you prove that SAT is in NP, you do it by showing how to verify that a given assignment satisfies the formula. There's no need for it to be easy to compute such an assignment. It's the same in this case. The function $\ell$ is polytime, and that's all you need.

Comment: So then to show that $L \in NP$, the unique $u$ is a good witness. But what about showing that $L \in coNP$?

Comment: I'll let you figure out the answer to that on your own. You need to use the fact that $\ell$ is one-to-one. Make sure that you know what that means.